# Changing password after successful login with Okta API

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm currently building an application that uses Okta for authentication, and I'd like to build a feature that allows users to change their password once they've logged in. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find an endpoint that will serve this purpose. The main change password API, api/v1/authn/credentials/change_password only works for users currently in the PASSWORD_WARN, and PASSWORD_EXPIRED states. Is there any way to use this or another similar endpoint once the user has logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this case you'll want to look at the [Users API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html) (and specifically the [Change Password section](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#change-password)).

Generally, the */api/v1/authn/credentials/change_password* endpoint that you mentioned in the prompt is strictly for the authn flow - it's the endpoint you use to transition the user from PASSWORD_WARN or PASSWORD_EXPIRED to the next [authentication state](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#transaction-state) (by providing a new password).

The */api/v1/users/:id/credentials/change_password* endpoint can be called at any time by your backend service, and doesn't strictly require the user to be authenticated - it's not CORS enabled and you'll need to provide an ApiToken when sending a request to it.